# Httpd service not starting in Alpine docker image

Tags: apache, docker, alpine-linux

Trying to run both java and http service in a single Alpine image. The httpd service is failing some how.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache apache2-proxy apache2-ssl apache2-utils

WORKDIR /var/www/
COPY html/ .

WORKDIR /var/backed
COPY backed-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 8085/tcp

CMD [“sh”,"-c","/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND && java -jar /var/backed/backed-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Docker run command:

```
$ sudo docker run -p 8080:80 -p 8085:8085 server:1.0

AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.1.8.RELEASE ::
:: https://www.jhipster.tech ::
```

Posted snipped of the container run above, I think the httpd service quits immediately.

I am able to view jhipster home page on 172.17.0.2:8085, but frontend 172.17.0.2:8080 or 172.17.0.2 gets "connection timed out".

How can make the front end work?

Comment: you need to check the apache error logs in the container

Comment: Standard practice here is to run these in two separate containers.  That would also simplify things here by letting you try to fix your httpd setup in isolation.